# Quick way to email results of a mysql query

Tags: mysql, linux

Is there a simple way to email the results of a mysql query from either the mysql console directly or from the linux console?  Nice formatting is a bonus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql -u .. -p.. -H <<<"your query" | mutt -s 'subject' email@email.com
```

*if you consider HTML is better formatting*

personally, i prefer `\G`

```
mysql -u .. -p.. -N <<<"your query\G" | mail -s 'subject' email@email.com
```

Comment: using the -H option actually makes the HTML tags visible in the email, since it mail sends it with a text/plain content type.

Comment: this is true, it should possible to fix via some setting on mutt (sorry, dun have the exact answer yet)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the other mutt answer is just plain old `mail` from the mailx package:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass dbname < queryfile.sql | mail -s 'Your query output' email@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <database> -e "<query>" | sendmail <emailaddress>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't build upon anything not already submitted. Answering old questions without building upon previously submitted responses is entirely pointless.

Comment: The answer leverages the '-e <query>' command line option which for many purposes significantly simplifies things as it does not require a external .sql file to read the query from. I forgot to mention to add the -H/--html command line option to make the output HTML.